# How can I create an new array for each specific data in a loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have this function:

```
flotLinea:function(tareas){

var self = this;
console.info(tareas);
     var aTar = new Array();

        for(var i = 0;i<tareas.length;i++){

          var val = new Array(new Date(tareas[i].fecha_registro),tareas[i].porcentaje);
                aTar.push(val);
        }

    console.info(aTar);

},
```

Using `console.info(tareas);` print this :

[image]

And using `console.info(aTar);` print :

[image]

(The data from tareas always is changing because the data comes from a dropdown)

I need create an new array for each id_usu using the same data , how can I do this?

For example in this case I need an array for id_usu = 4 ( are two id_usu = 4, so i need the data where id_usu = 4) , one array with id_usu = 6 and one array with id_usu = 9

I need do this , because this data are for a chart, so, after , each user ( id_usu ) will be a different color in that chart.

Comment: Can you add an example of the desired output?

Comment: Use multidimensional arrays.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript

Comment: It's not really clear at all what you're trying to do? Do you want to join the values so that when the ID is the same, those values are somehow bundled together ?

Comment: @adeneo yes mm.. If I selected an option in a dropdown, the data from that option is save in "tareas" . With those data I need draw a chart, and I need a different color for each user, but that is after, now i need separate each user(id_usu) when the data is in that function ( sorry my english )

Comment: @Jeanbf I've provided a solution with whatever I could understand from your problem.

Answer (score 1):

From whatever I have understood form your problem statement and the code you have provided, I've provided a solution below.

```
flotLinea:function(tareas){

    var self = this;
    console.info(tareas);
     var aTar = new Array();
     var idArray = [];

        for(var i = 0;i<tareas.length;i++){
            if(idArray.indexOf(tareas[i].id_usu) == -1){
              var val = new Array(new Date(tareas[i].fecha_registro),
                  tareas[i].porcentaje);
                idArray.push(tareas[i].id_usu);
                aTar.push(val);
               }
             else{
                   for(var j = 0; j < aTar.length; j++){
                        if(tareas[i].id_usu == aTar[j][0].id_usu){
                           aTar[j].length = new Array(new Date(tareas[i].fecha_registro)
                      ,tareas[i].porcentaje);     
                         }
                     }
                 }
        }

    console.info(aTar);

}
```

I'm using **Brute-Force** kind of solution, performance can always be increased.

I've created on new array above as `idArray` to hold the unique `id_usu`s, and am comparing if the current `tareas[i].id_usu` already is there in that array, if not push the new value to `aTar` array and `tareas[i].id_usu` to `idArray`, else loop over the `aTar` array and find the array which already has the object with the current `tareas[i].id_usu` and push the new values at `aTar[j].length`.